# Remove a commit from github remote with commit number

Tags: git, github

I have a 2 days old commit. How can I remove a particular git commit from remote permanently? So that it can not be visible from browser with that commit number.

Comment: You can't, not without rewriting the history of the branch.

Comment: But it is not right to change the history, right? I have re-base and delete the commit and force push it. but still it is showing with that commit number.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by commit number in GitHub, but Git uses a SHA-1 hash to label its commits (and ideally they should always be unique).  If you nuked that commit, then it should be gone from the history.

Answer (score 1):

If you still can access that commit, after having rebasing and dropping said commit, and force pushing a branch, that means it is still referenced by another branch.

Removing a commit from a branch only removes it from the repo (and store it in the local repo [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)) if no other branches reference it.